# What did Yasaburou mean by calling himself a "Bohemian Tanuki"?

Tags: the-eccentric-family

What does Yasaburou Shimogamo mean when in episode 7 (00:36) he says: "Even for a Bohemian tanuki like me..."

I thought tanuki were a Japanese thing. Do tanuki exist in Eastern Europe?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I doubt Yasaburou was insinuating that he was from the traditional Czech lands. Instead he meant [Bohemianism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bohemianism), which is used to describe people of unconventional lifestyles.

Also see: [Urban dictionary](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=bohemian), [Merriam Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/bohemian), [Dictionary.com](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/bohemian).

- a person (as a writer or an artist) living an unconventional life usually in a colony with others
- pertaining to or characteristic of the unconventional life of a bohemian.
- living a wandering or vagabond life, as a Gypsy.